# Element from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, element

I have the next JSON object but I can't get latitude and longitude from it. In JavaScript every time I try I get undefined error:

```
{
    "response": {
        "date_ts": 1352514978,
        "raw": {
            "profile": "realtime",
            "battery": -100,
            "battery_state": "unknown"
        },
        "uuid": "b191d0d4-a967-47c9-b58b-3b491c8247db",
        "location": {
            "position": {
                "altitude": 0,
                "speed": -4,
                "horizontal_accuracy": 5,
                "latitude": 37.785834,
                "longitude": -122.406417,
                "heading": 0,
                "vertical_accuracy": 0
            },
            "type": "point"
        },
        "date": "2012-11-09T20:36:18-06:00"
    },
    "type": "onSuccess",
    "source": {}
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: How about the JavaScript code which causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON before you can manipulate it as a complex object structure.

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(myjson);

console.log(parsed.response.location.position.longitude);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/VwWvP/

Comment: Thanks a lot, i forgot parse data, jsfidle great tool i did not know. again thanks!!!

Comment: Again its me I'm kind of new with this objects things, sorry if is to obvious my question thanks to the previous answer i ve learned how to get data from a json parse but now what happens when in my object i need all the same items inside, i mean all the 'location' but the structure changes every time for example this http://jsfiddle.net/8kGwg/

Comment: @Chicken: You need to write code to accommodate any lookups you need. The more predictable/repetitive the object structure is, the easier it is to do it in a loop. But the more variation there is, the more code you need to write. For example, `response.points` is an Array of objects that have a `.location`, but `response.end` directly reference the object with the `.location`. You need code to cover both situations.

Comment: Thanks you are right, this Json object is the result of geolocation Api, i think i have to study more the resultant object. This is my first time here in stackoverflow you really helped me, again thanks!!